# why is joinedAt showing as today’s date?

Tags: discord.js

It’s not showing the real date as results. Instead it shows today’s date. Why?

My code:

`${moment(member.joinedAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY | LT")}`

Comment: Try using `joinedTimestamp` and see if you get the same result

Comment: @Giuliopime yes, same result.